# Can I set windows audio to Stereo while VIA driver is 5.1?

Tags: audio, speakers, surround-sound, stereo, 5.1

I have a 3.1 audio setup (2 front, 1 center, 1 subwoofer) and I want to use only these in games - but what happens is the games are sending audio to the Rear channels which are disconnected, therefore I lose sounds often (from behind)

Can I force games system-wide to output stereo (and let the driver do the upmix) or set Windows Sound to Stereo while driver is still set at 5.1?

I use Windows 7
Gigabyte GA-Z77X-UD3H with VIA HD VT2021
"ENVY HD"
Package Version-11.3.0.0.32 (Driver Version-6.0.11.0300)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about modifying speaker configuration manually and selecting stereo instead of 5.1? (Right-click volume icon > Playback devices > Select speakers or digital output or other device and click the Configure button.)

Comment: What this does is disabling the center and subwoofer, which is something I don't want -  I want their fill without losing audio...

Comment: Temporarily I connected (very) low quality speakers to my system just so I wont lose the rear channels... Still can't seem to find a solution